# How to download certificate from LDAPS (not LDAP) using Linux Utilities?

Tags: linux, openssl, ldap

I tried following in linux:

```
[wildfly@alq-esb-app02 log]$ echo -n | openssl s_client -connect cdc201.cop.copcommon.com:636 | sed -ne '/-BEGIN CERTIFICATE-/,/-END CERTIFICATE-/p' > ldapserver.pem
depth=1 DC = com, DC = corpcommon, DC = corp, CN = EVRY Issuing CA03
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:0
DONE
```

Any idea how to download certificate from LDAPS (May be through linux)

Comment: You already did. Look in the file.

Comment: But does it work for LDAPS?

Comment: @dave_thompson_085: Also what is unable to get local issuer certificate